# How to pull closest string in an excel range where vlookup doesnt work?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a string [image] and want to find the nearest string in an ordered table below.

I tried using `Vlookup(string, range, 1, false)`, but don't get the value I want.

In this case I need a function that returns  'BTC-25MAR22-80000-C

[image]

Comment: A few more details will surely help. Do all the other criteria (delimited through hyphen) in your string have to match? Is that numeric substring the only part you don't mind matching?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do some sort of approximate matching, such as that done by the Fuzzy Lookup add-in from Microsoft https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=15011